# Why end some selectors in `:alias` and others don't?

Tags: skinning, trinidad

Looking at the documentation of [trinidad skinning selectors](http://myfaces.apache.org/trinidad/skin-selectors.html#Global_Selectors) I noticed that some selectors end in `:alias` and others don't. For example:

```
.AFLabelDisabled:alias  Aliased style class that is included in the label selector for all the form components when they are disabled. It is a quick way to style disabled form components' labels the same, instead of for each component: .AFLabelDisabled:alias instead of e.g., "af|inputText:disabled af|inputText::label".
.AFErrorIconStyle   Style class that styles the .AFErrorIcon:alias icons.
```

There is even this selector, with and without the `:alias`:

```
.AFRequiredIconStyle    Style class that styles the .AFRequiredIcon icon.
.AFRequiredIconStyle:alias  Alias style class that styles the required icon for form components. It is included in the ::required-icon-style pseudo-element for the form components (e.g. af|inputText::required-icon-style)
```

I read the [devguide on alias skinning](http://myfaces.apache.org/trinidad/devguide/skinning.html#Alias_skinning_keys), but that didn't help.

What exactly is the `:alias` for?

Comment: Control-f ":alias". I don't even know what this is and i'll answer it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Directly from the docs

> If you want to change the font-family to Arial for everything, then
>   you need to do a replace of every use of Tahoma to Arial. Well, in
>   skinning you don't need to do this. You can use the :alias feature. A
>   skin selector that ends in :alias is one that never gets written out
>   to the generated CSS-2 stylesheet. Instead it is included in other
>   skin selectors and is useful in that you can change css properties in
>   one place, not in tens or maybe hundreds of places.